# Django south schemamigration KeyError

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am trying to do a schemamigration in Django with **south** using the following command where `core` is the app I would like to migrate.

`$ python manage.py schemamigration core --auto`

Unfortunately this throws the following `KeyError`:

`KeyError: u"The model 'externaltoolstatus' from the app 'core' is not available in this migration."`

Does anybody know a way to how figure out what went wrong or where/when this error was thrown during the migration?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the last migration files were accidentally corrupted and caused the `KeyError`.

Comment: Could you provide more information about the corruption ? What did go wrong, and if you know it, how to prevent it?

Comment: Someone made a mistake and change the modules names within the old migration files so south couldn't find a module. This question should probably be deleted. Sorry.